# grep -v under double quotes query

Tags: grep, double-quotes, quoting

We have a portion of code which states,

```
"diff file1 file2 | /usr/bin/grep -v "#" |  /usr/bin/grep ^\>  |  /usr/bin/awk '{print $3}' | /usr/bin/xargs mkdir"
```

The whole statement is enclosed in double quotes(is a requirement of the application syntax). When the application reaches this stage , it gives the grep error.
This statement works well on the command line. But through application, gives error for grep.

> Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
>
> Try `grep --help' for more information.

So not sure if it is first grep or second grep which is a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a problem with double quotes. Try changing  your first grep to `/usr/bin/grep -v '#'` and the second grep to `/usr/bin/grep '^>'`

Answer (score 0):

You are using `grep -v ^>` and `>` means "redirect".

If you for example do:

```
grep ^>output
```

all the output will be stored in the file `output`.

So what you need to do is to quote `^>` so that it is interpreted as the pattern you are looking for:

```
"diff file1 file2 | /usr/bin/grep -v "#" | /usr/bin/grep "^>" | /usr/bin/awk '{print $3}' | /usr/bin/xargs mkdir"
                                                         ^  ^
```

By the way, note all your `grep`s can be reduced like this:

```
diff file1 file2 | awk '/#/ || /^>/ {print $3}' | /usr/bin/xargs mkdir
                        ^^^ ^^ ^^^^
          either contains #  |   |
                             or starts with >
```

Comment: well it doesn't make any sense to change from double to single quotes in this case, but...